# Geocoding Marker on Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

Whenever I search an address into google maps and geocode it, my map doesn't add a marker until I run the search a second time. Can anyone tell me why that is? 
Basically I search an address, run through the name of it into a 3rd party geocoder, and mutate a global marker I created on the map. This is so I only have one marker at a time on the map. For some reason though, it never places the marker the first time I search for an address, I have to search for another address. The weird thing is, it doesn't have to be the same address, if I enter another address it will just change the title of the marker, putting where I originally wanted it to go.

My code:

```
extension EventCreatorVC: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewControllerDelegate {
func resultsController(_ resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController,
                       didAutocompleteWith place: GMSPlace) {
    searchController?.isActive = false
    // Do something with the selected place.
    print("Place name: \(place.name)")
    print("Place address: \(place.formattedAddress)")
    print("Place attributions: \(place.attributions)")

    Nominatim.getLocation(fromAddress: place.name, completion: {(error, location) -> Void in

        let latitude = (location!.latitude as NSString).doubleValue
        let longitude = (location!.longitude as NSString).doubleValue

        self.locationOfMarker =  CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)

    })

    markerPlace(locationOfMarker: locationOfMarker, name: place.name)

}

func markerPlace(locationOfMarker: CLLocationCoordinate2D, name: String) {
    marker.position = locationOfMarker
    marker.title = name


}

func resultsController(_ resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController,
                       didFailAutocompleteWithError error: Error){
    // TODO: handle the error.
    print("Error: ", error.localizedDescription)
}

// Turn the network activity indicator on and off again.
func didRequestAutocompletePredictions(forResultsController resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController) {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
}

func didUpdateAutocompletePredictions(forResultsController resultsController: GMSAutocompleteResultsViewController) {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
}
}
```

Comment: put that markerplace line into your completion handler part. As per block, when it finds result then it return to completion part. So try it on debugging mode , I think that markerplace line runs first then it goes to completion part

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure what you mean. Where should I put the line?

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: Please check my changes in my answer. It am sure solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now your problem is like your compeletion part take some time to get finished. So I make it delay with this change to your code as

```
Nominatim.getLocation(fromAddress: place.name, completion: {(error, location) -> Void in

                let latitude = (location!.latitude as NSString).doubleValue
                let longitude = (location!.longitude as NSString).doubleValue

                self.locationOfMarker =  CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
                let delayTime = DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(0.5 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: delayTime)
                {
                    self.markerPlace(locationOfMarker: self.locationOfMarker, name: "")
                    self.mapView.animate(toLocation: self.locationOfMarker)
              }
        })
```

Change method as per mine sure it will solve your issue. 
Thank you for your support

Comment: Thank you so much! Very interesting solution

Comment: I send you invitation in hangout, We will chat for your work Please accept my invitation